# Java Glassfish - Too many files open

Tags: java, mongodb, glassfish, socketexception

I am having a backend deployment running on a glassfish server, the frontend of my application sends REST request when it needs some data. Also, the backend is connected to a Mongo database:

FRONTEND <----rest---->BACKEND<---->DB .

My backend is deployed on an Ubuntu virtual machine via glassfish 5, the frontend is running on an Apache web server.

After some use, may we say after 5 minutes, and especially when multiple users are using the application, the glassfish server crashes most of the time while attempting to access the database with the error: `java.net.SocketException: Too many open files`.

Of course, I have googled this issue already and there are many suggestions that say just to increase the number of open files which is right now at `1024`.

My question to this point is now, what are these open files, and even if I increase them, would the limit not also be reached after some time. Is increasing the only solution or may there be an error in my codings? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is a snip of the netstat output of my ubuntu machine:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44856         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44980         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44794         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45132         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44764         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44814         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44756         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44374         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44926         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45040         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45276         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44858         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45052         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45310         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44806         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44840         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45046         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45222         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45160         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44990         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44914         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:45274         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44998         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         localhost:44788         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45176         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45136         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45058         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44926         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44968         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45190         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45050         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44886         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45308         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44978         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45086         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45198         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44922         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44938         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:45020         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44896         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44830         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44960         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:44776         localhost:27017         ESTABLISHED 5204/java
```

As you can see there is a way to establish connections with localhost:27017 which is the mongo database.

Comment: It sounds like you are not closing connections/sockets.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but how do I do it?

Comment: Given we don't have your code, we can't possibly know. If you create a socket connection, make sure you close it, if you open a database connection, make sure you close it, etc, etc.